# Use of uninitialized value warning while checking "if defined <variable>"

Tags: perl

Here is the snippet of a big code, it prints `Use of uninitialized value $match in string eq at <script path> line 7.` if there is no match.

I am using `if (!defined $match)`, should it not suppress this warning? I am using Perl version 5.18

```
my $match = '';
my $prematch = '';
my $i = 1;
$obj->{comm}->print( $command ); #$obj->{comm} is Net::Telnet
while ($match eq '' and $i < 3) {
   ( $prematch, $match ) = $obj->{comm}->waitfor( Match => "/$pattern/");
   print "\npattern not found, try again..." if (!defined $match); #line 7
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: The warning is about `eq`, not `defined`, so the issue is probably in `while ($match eq '' and $i < 3) {`. I'm guessing `$obj->{comm}->waitfor` is setting `$match` to undef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

waitfor seems to be setting $match to undef, at least some of the time.

`while (! length $match && $i < 3)` is the easiest way to check if it is not empty or defined, at least in non-ancient perls.  Or, if waitfor never sets it to an empty string, just don't set it to that yourself (`my $match;`) and use `while (! defined $match && $i < 3)` .

Comment: I'm not keen on convolving the test for the number of retries with the success of the match. `while (! length $match && $i < 3)` doesn't shout to me *try twice for a match and then give up*

Comment: @Borodin yes, your answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

This is awkward because you must initialise `$i` (which isn't an index and so should be `$n`) and `$match` just to engineer a `do` ... `while` instead of a `while ...`do`

It looks like a case for an endless loop with interposed checks for the end-loop condition, but you want to try things only twice, so a simple `for` loop will do

Something like this perhaps?

```
$obj->{comm}->print($command);

my $match;

for ( 1 .. 2 ) {

    my $prematch;

    ($prematch, $match) = $obj->{comm}->waitfor(Match => "/$pattern/");

    last if defined $match;

    print "\npattern not found, try again...";
}

# Here $match will still be undefined if there was no match after two tries
```

Comment: I would have done `(my $prematch, $match) = ...`, but I know that bothers some people.  I also would do `for my $try (1..2)` and avoid setting even an unused `$_`.

Comment: @ysth: `my ($prematch, $match)` wouldn't work because `$match` needs a larger scope. Nice point about the loop control variable though—I don't know yet what Perl 6 does about `$_` but I'm pleased about everything else I've seen

Comment: my my was in the parens

Comment: @ysth: Does that change anything?

Comment: it only affects the following variable, not anything else in the list

Comment: @ysth: Ah, so it's the same as `(my ($prematch), $match) = ...` I think that's far too subtle. Write it with these parentheses and I would be on board. But in this case all that is required seems to be `(undef, $match) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
my $match = '';
my $prematch = '';
my $i = 1;
$obj->{comm}->print( $command ); #$obj->{comm} is Net::Telnet
while (!$match and $i < 3) {
   ( $prematch, $match ) = $obj->{comm}->waitfor( Match => "/$pattern/");
   print "\npattern not found, try again..." if (!$match); #line 7
   $i++;
}
```

By assigning '' to $match you are actually defining it.  Your code would work if $match = undef; like so

```
my $match = undef;
my $prematch = '';
my $i = 1;

while (!defined $match and $i < 3) {
    print "\npattern not found, try again..." if (!defined $match); #line 7
    $i++;
}
```